# on submit doesn't capture event inside modal

Tags: ajax, bootstrap-modal, submit, jquery-events

I have and inside it I have the form tag with its id, since the form is large I put it on another file and call it with php

```
        <div class="modal fade" id="general" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="generalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="generalLabel">Historia clinica general</h5>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <form method="POST" role="form" id="hcgeneral">
                                <?php require 'addHcg.php' ?>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

and then there's the jquery code, where I have the ajax request, before it I have the submit event with the id of the form but it doesn't capture it and I don't know why because I already did something exactly like this

```
    $('#hcgeneral').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault()
    
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'procHcg.php',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: {
                id_paciente: $('input[id="id_paciente"]').val(),
                embarazo: $('.embarazo').val(),
                padreConvida: $('.padreVivo').val(),
                enfermedadPadre: $('#enfPadre').val(),
                madreConVida: $('.madreViva').val(),
                enfermedadMadre: $('#enfMadre').val(),
                hermanos: $('.hnos').val(),
                hnoSano: $('#hnoSano').val(),
                sufreEnfermedad: $('.sufreEnf').val(),
                queEnfSufre: $('#pacEnf').val(),
                tratMedico: $('.haceTrat').val(),
                cualTratMedico: $('#tratMedico').val(),
                medHabituales: $('#medConsume').val(),
                med5anios: $('#medicamentos5').val(),
                deporte: $('.deporte').val(),
                malestarDeporte: $('.malestar').val(),
                extraccionMuela: $('#sacaMuela').val(),
                sangraMuela: $('#sangraMuela').val(),
                colageno: $('.probColageno').val(),
                fiebre: $('.fiebre').val(),
                fiebreProtege: $('#protegeMed').val(),
                diabetico: $('.diabetico').val(),
                diabetesControl: $('.diabetesControl').val(),
                diabetesMed: $('#diabetesMed').val(),
//and more data...
        },
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response)
                alert('La historia clinica general se ha guardado exitosamente.')
            },
            error: function (jqXMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus);
                alert(errorThrown)
            }
            
        })
```

What I want is to see the postDatos in the console and to sent them in procHcg.php but nothing returns

Comment: If you want help, you should do better at upvoting and choosing correct answers. From your last 10 questions, you marked a correct answer on only 3 of them. Why should anyone work to help you, only to be ignored?

Comment: someone of them have just comments and other have the solution but I don't know why I didn't vote them! I'm sorry

Comment: Most people who answer questions are competing to give the best answer and win the "checkmark" for the question. Questioners can say "Thank you" in two ways: (a) by upvoting helpful answers, and (b) by choosing one answer as the best answer. Both actions ***cost nothing*** to the person who opened the question, but they are important to the people who try to help.  This is the genius of StackOverflow - Jeff Atwood and Joel Spolsky found a way to make helping other people fun. StackOverflow is a big game so play the game! It costs you nothing, so upvote some and always choose a best answer.

Comment: It is okay to **not** choose a best answer if your question remains unanswered. Two possibilities: (a) the question is too broad and you are asking someone to do your project for you - don't do that. Ask lots and lots of small questions, don't ask for complete solutions. Or, (b) none of the answers is good enough. In that case, please make it clear (add comments) what the problem is or why the answers don't work for you. If an answer points you in the right direction and you solve it yourself, that answer solved your question - checkmark. If it was really helpful, checkmark ***and*** upvote.

Comment: thank you for helping me realize what I was doing wrong,for now I will pay more attention. I will keep in mind the advice about how question are made, I think this one is clear, I did all the code and I just wanted someone to point out what I was doing wrong or how could I find the error. Again, thank you for helping me to understand more this, I wasn't doing it on purpose.